# GridView onTouchListener not working as i expected

Tags: java, android

pls help with my problem:

i have a gridview and a touchListener on its elements. The problem is when i touch an element i want to change it s background and when the touch is finished(Action up or ouside) to display the initial background. the problem is when i m tapping over an element then drag my finger over another element, the initial element change it s background, but after i drag the finger over another element and finish the touch the background of the first element touched is not changing to the initial background. the idea is that when  i touch down an elemnt from the gridview to get his lock. this is may code:

```
package com.mines.gui.components; 

import android.content.Context; 
import android.graphics.Bitmap; 
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable; 
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.MotionEvent; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.BaseAdapter; 
import android.widget.GridView; 
import android.widget.ImageView; 

import com.mines.globals.GlobalVariables; 

public class MinesView extends GridView { 

    private int[] length = new int[81]; 
    private final Bitmap grid0 = Bitmap.createBitmap(GlobalVariables.icons, 0, 88, 50, 50); 
    private final Bitmap grid1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(GlobalVariables.icons, 50, 88, 50, 50); 
    private int id; 

    public MinesView(Context context) { 
        super(context); 

        setAdapter(new MineAdapter(context)); 
        setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH); 
        setNumColumns(9); 
        setHorizontalSpacing(40); 
    } 

    class MineAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 

        private Context context; 

        public MineAdapter(Context context) { 
            this.context = context; 
        } 

        public Object getItem(int position) { 
            return position; 
        } 

        public long getItemId(int position) { 
            return position; 
        } 

        public int getCount() { 
            return length.length; 
        } 

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
            final ImageView imageView; 

            if(convertView == null) { 
                imageView = new ImageView(context); 
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(40, 40)); 
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP); 
            } else { 
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView; 
            } 
            imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(grid0)); 
            imageView.setId(position); 

            imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { 
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) { 

                    switch (arg1.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) { 
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:  
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: 
                            imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(grid1)); 
                        break; 
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE: 
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:  
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:  
                            imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(grid0)); 
                        break; 
                    } 
                    return false; 
                } 
            }); 

            imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

                public void onClick(View arg0) { 
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

                } 
            }); 

            return imageView; 
        } 

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Out This code...
create ontouchlistener for gridview.

```
 public class HelloGridViewActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sample_0);
                    Log.v("log_tag", "MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN");
                    return true;
                }
                else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {

                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(null); 
                    Log.v("log_tag", "MotionEvent.ACTION_UP");
                    return true; 
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

Comment: does not work does not even enter in if's loop. i don t know if view recognies when i touch on a grid's element

Comment: i resolved th problem by changihg the super class from button to checkbox.. dudes...be more helpful pls with an android beginner